# How to use item templates for dropdown lists in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need to customize dropdownlist in asp.net and add checkboxes to make it a multi selection list. Can I do it using item templates. If so, how? Also wanted to know if I can have tri state checkboxes?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop down lists are rendered as "select" type inputs in HTML. So, you can't format them to contain checkboxes. However, you can make use of a checkboxlist control, placing it in a div to present the desired control.

This site seems to have a solution: http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/42/211693.aspx

Or you can try looking up a jQuery UI control for this.

Comment: Also, you can look into Telerik controls for ASP.NET Ajax which might have a drop down list control with check boxes.